# Can props for bootstrap-vue-tables be set dynamically from parent components?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I use a Bootstrap-Vue-Table (`b-table`) inside a Vue-Component (`BTableGenericComponent.vue`). As the name suggests, I reuse the table in multiple other components/pages. In one of them, I want to enable the `stacked` prop for the table, on the others I don't. Can I pass the prop somehow dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a prop in your `BTableGenericComponent.vue`, and bind it to the `stacked` prop on your `b-table`. Set the default of the prop to `false`, so that by default the table wont be stacked. But will allow you to add the prop in your parent component if needed.

#### BTableGenericComponent.vue

```html
<b-table :stacked="stacked"></b-table>

<script>
{
  props: {
    stacked: {
      type: [Boolean, String],
      default: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in your parent component you can now use the prop when you need the table to be stacked.

#### Parent.vue

```html
<b-table-generic-component :stacked="true"></b-table-generic-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes dynamically setting props could work in every component not just Bootstrap-Vue-Table.

Parent component

```
 <ChildComponent
   prop-1="Text"
   :prop-2="2"
 />
```

Child component

```
<template>
  <AnotherChild v-bind="$props" />
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   props: {
    prop1: String,
    prop2: Number
   }
 }
</script>
```

Btw, declaring every prop in the child component, might NOT be a good idea. Instead you can combine props and attributes.

Parent component

```
 <ChildComponent
   prop-1="Text"
   :prop-2="2"
   attr-1="attr"
   attr-2="attr2"
 />
```

Child component

```
<template>
  <AnotherChild v-bind="$props" v-bind="$attrs" />
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   props: {
    prop1: String,
    prop2: Number
   }
 }
</script>
```

If you want to solve you exact problem without me being too general in my answer, feel free to provide a codesandbox example, so I can edit it and provide you the solution.